# C++ flex obtener código leído y pasarlo a otro archivo

Tags: c, c++11, flex

tengo un proyecto donde tengo que pasar el código leído por flex que en este caso sería un archivo pascal y de ahí lo que tengo que hacer es poner ese código en un archivo LaTex(.tex) no sé como hacer para que después de que flex lo analice pasarlo a mi archivo .tex
El código funciona con estos comandos

```
flex source.l 
g++ lex.yy.cc
./a.out
```

Se escribe el archivo con la extension por ejemplo test.pascal y que tenga un pequeño loop con un if para que el flex lo lea
Después crea un archivo PDF.tex que se compila con pdflatex PDF.tex y listo lo que tengo que pasar es el código de test.pascal al PDF.tex

```
%{ 
#include <iostream>   
#include <fstream>   
#include <string>   
using namespace std;   

int tk_if = 0;

%}


%%

if  ++tk_if;

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE *fp;
    char filename[50], c;
    printf("Enter the filename: \n");
    scanf("%s",filename);
    fp = fopen(filename,"r");

  

  if (fp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "file null";
        exit(0);
    } else 
    {

 

   string code;

while(1) {
    c = fgetc(fp);
    if (feof(fp)) {
        break;
    }
    code = printf("%c", c);
}

   

 yyin = fp;
    //start of lex
    yylex();    
   

 
//create latex file
ofstream myPDF("PDF.tex");

   

 myPDF  << " \\documentclass{article} "
            << "\\title{Scanner}"
            << "\\author{Andrés}"
            << "\\date{III Cuatrimestre Diciembre del 2021 }"
            << " number of if's " 
            << tk_if
            << " \\end{document} ";

   

 myPDF.close();
}

 

fclose(fp); 
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No lo haces *después* que lo pasas por Flex. Hazlo *mientras* que lo pasas. Es decir, en tus reglas de Flex, hay que mandar  el texto reconocido --o sea `yytext`-- al archivo latex, acompañado con los códigos necesario para el formato deseado, color o lo que sea.

De allí, hay dos exigencias que deben ser medio obvios. Uno es que el ostream del archivo latex sea visible y ya inicializado. El otro es que tienes una regla para cualquier ingreso, en lugar de dejar parte del ingreso a la regla por defecto de Flex. De hecho, no  deberías nunca depender de la regla por defecto; tus reglas deberían poder reconocer todo.

En resumen:

```c
{ 
#include <iostream>   
#include <fstream>   
#include <string>   
using namespace std;   

int tk_if = 0;
ofstream myPDF; // Para que sea disponible dentro de yylex
%}


%%

if  { ++tk_if; myPDF << RED << yytext << NORMAL; }
  // Regla para cualquier otro caracter
.|\n { myPDF << yytext; }

%%


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
  // ...
  // Abrir myPDF y escribir la cabecellia
  yylex();
  // Escribir lo demás del archivo latex 
  // Cerrar el archivo
.
}
```

Comment: Eso era exactamente, gracias por la ayuda!